# Why $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x}{y^{2/3}}$ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to understand why this limit does not exist
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x}{y^{2/3}}
$$

If I consider $y=\pm x$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x^{2/3}} = 0
$$
But now I am not sure what other path I can take to find a different limit.

Can I consider $x=c$, $c\in \mathbb R$?

Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced. :)

Comment: Try $y=x^3$. $\,$

Comment: It simply have no sense on $y=0$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now @Gary Thanks for that. :) sometimes I just cannot see that the answer is right in front of you :( Well, I guess it takes time to learn this. :)

Comment: You cannot consider the path $x=c$ in general because you are not approaching $(0,0)$